# Spring Boot with proxy for outgoing requests (GCP)

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, proxy, router

I'm going to develop simple REST Client in Spring Boot.
Unfortunately, REST Service have got some limitation based on request count from one IP / minute.
I wonder if #GCP have got some ready solution to solve that problem. I'm thinking about some router/proxy. Let's say we have got 3 IPs so routing would look like:

```
RQ no 1 -> IP1
RQ no 2 -> IP2
RQ no 3 -> IP4
RQ no 4 -> IP1
RQ no 5 -> IP2
...
```

If not then probably I will have to implement own proxy/router that will delegate RQs to proper proxy.

Thanks

Comment: Please, take a look at [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview), perhaps it will be appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ut of the box product for that. However, you can imagine Cloud Functions proxy, that each uses their own serverless VPC connector, subnet and Cloud NAT.

Like this, create 3 Cloud Functions, and with you want to perform a call, randomly call one of the 3 functions. It should work, affordable and set up isn't too hard.